# LineRenderer not rendering correctly after build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a program in Unity that can visualize .gcode files(with help of my another program made in VS), but on some computers, you can see a few lines, but the lines are across the whole screen.. like if they're going into infinity...

This problem only occurred on my dad's and my brother's PC. It works on my PC including my notebook(which has an Intel GPU). All computers this was tested on have Win10 on them.

None of the computers (except mine) have Unity 3D installed on them(I don't have it installed on my notebook, yet it's still working).

**Any ideas why is this happening?**

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind... the problem was that my PC and my notebook's OS are in english, but my dad's brother's PCs are in Czech.

I will explain...

In Czech, the decimal separator is a comma, in English it's a dot.
But in English, a comma is a thousand separator.

Here's an example what the Unity program was working with:

```
[x;y;z]

55,643;80,393;1
55,624;80,016;1
55,643;79,607;1
55,624;80,016;1
55,643;80,393;1
171,096;114,498;1,2
171,221;114,233;1,2
171,395;113,999;1,2
171,612;113,802;1,2
171,862;113,652;1,2
172,139;113,553;1,2
172,457;113,51;1,2
```

(I always speak too soon..)